# ARKit Photogrammetry

Tags: computer-vision, arkit, realitykit, 3d-reconstruction, photogrammetry

For the last month, I have been researching ways to create 3D reconstructions from live video. It seems to me like the only option is to use a 3rd party service like Agisoft or Autodesk Capture. However, after the release of ARKit 2.0, I saw this [tweet](https://twitter.com/nobbis/status/972298968574013440?lang=en). In this tweet, Tim Field claims that he used ARKit photogrammetry to create 3D models. From what I know, this is impossible. I have only used ARKit to scan 3D objects and create point clouds. In fact this is what the [ARKit documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects) exactly:

> An [`ARReferenceObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceobject) contains only the spatial feature information needed for ARKit to recognize the real-world object, and is not a displayable 3D reconstruction of that object.

If what Tim Field is saying is true, how can I use ARKit to create 3D models using photogrammetry?

Comment: You might notice that said tweet predates the announcement of ARKit 2. Most likely, that demo is using a fair amount of custom processing on top of what ARKit provides, attempting to match per-frame pixel buffers to feature points and integrate them over time.

Answer (score 2):

Apple `RealityKit 2.0` got [Object Capture API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793918/lidar-and-realitykit-capture-a-real-world-texture-for-a-scanned-model). It provides us with the long-awaited photogrammetry tools. At the output we get USDZ model with a corresponding texture.

`ARKit 6.0 | 5.0 | 4.0` allows you make a `Scene Reconstruction` in real time if you're using a device with a LiDAR scanner. Scene Reconstruction occurs in nanosecond speed. A distance range is up to 5 meters (sometimes even more). For details watch [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/609/).

One of the key features of a LiDAR scanner is: it helps you eliminate everyday problems that you encounter at tracking and scene understanding stages. For instance: there's no need for physical movement and quality lighting conditions when tracking using LiDAR.

When reconstructed scene is ready, you get a polygonal geometry with `Occlusion Material` that you can immediately use for object occlusion, physics simulation and light estimation.

In addition to the above ARKit 6/5/4 gives you Depth API for managing a high-quality Depth channel, that now runs at 60 fps. Read [this webpage](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/arkit/) for more information.